# How to dynamically create index on JSON Object properties (JSON Object props are also dynamic)

Tags: hibernate-search

I have a scenario where I want to dynamically create index on keys of JSON Object (JSON Object attributes will vary). I am able to store the JSON Object as index (by implementing `FieldBridge`).

```
eg1: preference:{"sport":"football", "music":"pop")
eg2: preference:{"sport":"cricket", "music":"jazz", "cuisine":"mexican"}
```

But I am unable to query the individual fields like: 
`preference.sport`
or `preference.cuisine`

Is there any way / configuration in hibernate search through which we can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are dynamic, there is no pre-defined schema and Hibernate Search is unable to determine how to query these fields. There are significant differences in how a match query should be executed on a text field or a date field, for example.

For that reason, you cannot use the Hibernate Search Query DSL to build your queries.

However, you can use native APIs.

If you're using the Lucene integration, just creating the relevant queries yourself will work fine (as long as you create the right one):

```
new TermQuery(new Term("sport", "value"))
```

If you're using the experimental Elasticsearch integration, you can use `org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson( ... )`. You will have to write the whole query as JSON, though, and will not be able to take advantage of the Hibernate Search QueryBuilder at all, even for queries on statically defined fields. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_queries

Better support for native queries, as well as dynamic fields with pre-defined types, which would be targetable in the Query DSL, is planned for Hibernate Search 6, but it's not there yet. See [HSEARCH-3273](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3273).